# In IOS 7 how to implement a button in the settings

Tags: ios, button, ios7, application-settings

In Settings->General-Reset on an iPhone there is a list of blue text items that are , it seems to  me to all intents and purposes, a series of buttons. I would like to implement such a button in my app settings. However I can't work out how this is done. In the Apple documentation there is nothing about a PreferenceSpecifier that would show this behaviour. I feel that I must be being particularly stupid about this and am missing some trick here. Would someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you

Silas

Comment: Don't use external settings. Put a screen in your app. Then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: i dont' completely understand your question but this may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495266/best-practices-for-designing-table-view-for-app-settings/17495856#17495856

Answer (score 2):

Apple can run code in Settings.  You cannot.  You can only declaratively change entry values in your settings.